# zlib: compressed stream always the same?

Tags: compression, zlib

Is it guaranteed that for a given compression level and a given input, the compressed stream will always be the same, also for different (and upcoming) zlib versions?

Or is there some way I can make it like this?

Otherwise I would have to copy some specific zlib version to my project and stick to that. (Because I need that guarantee.)

Thanks,
Albert

Comment: Isn't the compression algorithm set by a standard? That'd make it very unlikely to change significantly in the future (quite apart from the enormous overhang of existing data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not guaranteed at all. Its possible to generate infinite different compressed streams
with the same zlib parameters. That's why there're things like 
gziphack: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.compression/browse_thread/thread/82fafc72949ed46c/0115418726ed45e1
http://www.advsys.net/ken/util/kzip.exe
http://www.advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.exe
http://www.walbeehm.com/download/DeflOpt207.7z
etc

Comment: Of course it is clear that there are many different compressed streams which uncompress to the same data. But that was not the question. The question was if the algorithm in zlib will always generate the same. Because in my use case, I need that.

Comment: I've tested zlib 114 and 121-125 and generated code seems to be identical with all options (there're little differences in zip archive headers though). But there're other libraries (for example, zlib version in Intel IPP) which can be used instead of zlib, and do generate different code even now. And there's no guarantee for future zlib versions either, as they might include parallel processing, or some other features, which would affect compression.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for zlib to break compatibility with such a huge installed base. There is zero chance that a zlib compressed stream built today will no longer be supported by a newer version of zlib anytime tomorrow or after tomorrow. **You can rest safely on this implicit guarantee** : the entire industry depends on zlib forward and backward compatibility.

Newer formats with no guarantee of interoperability will simply bring different names, such as 7zip for example.

Comment: Note that the question is *not* on whether it always *un*compresses in the same way, but whether the compressed bitstream is always the same, for some given uncompressed data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same version of zlib then the compression will be exactly the same.
Obviously, nobody can say anything on "upcoming versions".